# - (BOOL)webview: doesn't run in objective c xcode

Tags: objective-c, webview

I am trying to get this to run... I have put in NSLogs, but nothing appears in the debugger when I change page.

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webview.delegate = self;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"menu" ofType:@"html"     inDirectory:@"pages"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[request URL] absoluteString]); //this log appears when the ipad simulator starts
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

This section below doesn't seem to run (no log appears in the debugger!)

```
- (BOOL)webview:(UIWebView*)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[request URL] absoluteString]);
    NSString *absoluteUrl = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([absoluteUrl isEqualToString:@"didtap://button1"]) {

        NSLog(@"Button tapped");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i see you assigned the delegate, but did you also include the protocol name in your interface?

Comment: here is the code in the .h file:

    '#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>'

    '@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{'
    
        'IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;'
    }

    @property(nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webview;

    @end'

is this what you mean?

Sorry about the formatting im new to this

Comment: Ensure the webview is connected properly. Add this to the top of `viewDidLoad`: `NSLog(@"webview=%@", self.webview);`.  I don't like the fact that you've used the same name (`webview`) for the instance variable and the property; in fact you can drop the instance variable as `clang` will auto-create that for you these days.

Comment: when I add that code it outputs: webview=<UIWebView: 0x717d620; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x717d6b0>>

Comment: your header looks ok to me. cant see any mistale from here, but @trojanfoe is right. you should rename/get rid of the instance variable.

Comment: not that variable. in your .h-file, the property-WebView and the IBOutlet-WebView have the same name. it wont immediately solve your problem, but its bad style anyway. my suggestion: Add the IBOutlet to your property, then delete the instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the capitalization of your delegate method; it should be:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

i.e. `webView`, not `webview`.

Comment: @smj2393 Yeah easy mistake to make.